# How to lint and format newline after `yield` in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-3, scalafmt

How can I restrict the formatting of a Scala-3 project, so that newline is required after `yield` keyword?

For examples, I want this code to be rejected by linter/formatter

```scala
for
  a <- Some(1)
  b <- Some(2)
yield a + b
```

And the correct one would be:

```scala
for
  a <- Some(1)
  b <- Some(2)
yield
  a + b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool usually employed to format Scala source code is [scalafmt](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/).

By default, newlines after `yield` are removed, but you can preserve them by setting `newlines.avoidAfterYield` to `false` in your `.scalafmt.conf`.

Note that while this gets close to what you are looking for, it doesn't go all the way, as this prevents the removal of newlines after a `yield` but doesn't automatically add one.

If you feel strongly that this is a behavior that should be part of scalafmt, you can probably suggest it [to the maintainer](https://github.com/scalameta/scalafmt) and perhaps even contribute yourself. For reference, [this](https://github.com/scalameta/scalafmt/pull/1378) is the PR that introduced `newlines.avoidAfterYield`.